# How to use mongo/mongoose to connect to a remote database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a node js app in IP ex: 111.111.111.23:3000 I want to connect from my local express/node app script to my remote mongodb database. the database is running in the IP mention above but for some reason all i can do is connect to my local mongodb databse.

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
}
```

the code above is in my app.js and it works, but what I want to do is something like this.

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });

    mongoose.connect('mongodb:111.111.111.23:27017/test');
}
```

I tried adding the ip with and without the port but it fails.

My question is how do I connect to my remote database from my local machine ?

it case this help. The remote server is running ubuntu server 14.04 and I installed mongodb using this guide: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I get the following error:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 111.111.111.23:27017

Comment: You seem to be missing the `//` prefix before the IP address.

Comment: I added that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is your database password-protected? Does your server port forward external requests to `:27017`?

Comment: Does your server have a firewall?

Comment: my firewall is inactive.

Comment: my server is running on ubuntu 14.04 so by default the firewall in inactive.

Comment: Shouldn't you be connecting with a username/password to your remote database ?

Comment: i'm using ssh authentication so I can login to my remote server without a password.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mongoose connection format is:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database')
```

if you don't have username and password, just execute:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://host:port/database');
```

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

You could also try to connect using the mongo client and see if it works..

```
$ mongo 111.111.111.23:27017
```

Also, but not likely, make sure your mongod service is up.

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

Finnaly, make sure your firewall is down or open the port using:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code and still having the error: 
**error**:

```
E:\nodeJs>node mongoDBApi.js

E:\nodeJs\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:792
          throw err;
          ^
[object Object]
```

**code**:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://xxxx:xxxx@192.168.11.14:22/';


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("cdb");
  dbo.collection("ccollection").findOne({}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.info(result.name);
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: what if my password includes @  symbol?

Comment: const PASSWORD = encodeURIComponent('hello@123'); 

@DeepakTerse encode your password if it contains special characters

Answer (score 0):

code :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const DbConnector = () => {
  const DbConnectStr = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
  mongoose.connect(DbConnectStr, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Database Connected");
  });
};
module.exports = { DbConnector };
```